# Counting an aggregate result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am a novice SQL programmer, but have a question that I can't seem to find the answer to.

Suppose you have a table with two fields, like this:

```
ID         ReportText

100        aaaaaaaaa
100        bbbbbbbbb
101        ccccccccc
101        ddddddddd
```

I am trying to get a count of entries for each `ID`, that is:

```
ID         TotalCount

100        2
101        2
```

(Let's assume that all the entries are distinct.)

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read some books about development before starting to be a programmer? [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `count` with the `group by` seems to be enough :

```
select [id]
     , count(*) as [TotalCount]
from [tbl]
group by [id]
```